# Antisymmetric Lorentz parameters

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, lorentz-symmetry

In the expression for infinitesimal Lorentz transformation parameters omega appeare with all indices down and this forms antisymmetric matrix. What I think is that if we raise one of the indices up it is not antisymmetric. Is this true? Because if you use totally general form of this matrix with all indices down you can not get Lorentz boosts id est, generators for those, because you get antismmetric expression. So what I should do is raise the indices of the parameters matrix to get this part of the generators matrix to be ok?

Comment: I presume by an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation you're referring to the infinite product of infinitesimal Lorentz transformations. The $\omega$ rotation parameter is a matrix not a tensor, and yes it's anti-symmetric in the sense $\omega=-\omega^{T}$. Why don't you show us the problem?

Comment: Please write out your math so we can see what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you get
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\alpha\beta} + \omega_{\beta\alpha} = 0
\end{equation}
But you can still raise any of these indices and get:
\begin{equation}
\omega^{\alpha} ._{\beta} + \omega_{\beta} .^{\alpha} = 0
\end{equation}
The first equation shows the antisymmetry explicitly, the second one shows that your $\omega$ is traceless.

Comment: But how then do you get boost parameters that are actually symetric?

Comment: When having up and down indices, you can't talk about symmetry. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are living in different spaces. For more details, check https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315970/is-a-tensor-which-is-symmetric-in-two-indices-still-symmetric-after-raising-lowe

Answer (score 0):

By $\omega^\alpha\,_{\beta}$ = -$\omega_\beta\,^{\alpha}$ we are comparing signs of components of two matrix for infinitesimal rotation. (For example: $\omega^3\,_{2}$ = -$\omega^2\,_{3}$). One of them used to rotate contravariant and other covariant 4-vectors.

When lowering one index of each one, we get an antisymmetric matrix $\omega$, where for each component: $\omega_\alpha\,_{\beta}$ = -$\omega_\beta\,_{\alpha}$. It is not an infinitesimal rotation matrix.